# URI to Bitmap C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, bitmap, uri, webcam.js

I am capturing a URI in ASP.NET MVC with webcam.js. I would like to turn this URI to to bitmap in C#. Below is my current code for attempting to parse the URI into a bitmap, but it, but it gives error `"Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string"` when creating the byte buffer. I've also tried pulling it in as a C# Uri type, but haven't had any luck.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Scan(string file)
{
   Bitmap img = null;
   var matchGroups = Regex.Match(file, @"^data:((?<type>[\w\/]+))?;base64,(?<data>.+)$").Groups;
   var base64Data = matchGroups["data"].Value;
   byte[] byteBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data);
   MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteBuffer);
   memoryStream.Flush();
   memoryStream.Position = 0;
   img = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(memoryStream);
}
```

Here is my URI that is posted from the webcam.js object data_uri which renders the image fine in html.

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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 q2GiAMgrLbb5Oix4hx4UrBAPgKMD4/ZPYcxOE3ow52oDYa3ERwnNJBjgKIERPgLLak4jCl6f6CzZD/0WTByeVrh3sU8PkRGVnLTVBZITtbgJtMyD5lMc/wCnnKa0kHJ/qo yVCJZIOE3dHlMDjJ9j5SJjjlJuQDyNo55WHu3gCVGST5KcPupq3bQWZjaMrLHQclNMH2KyOQAqpILJN/7JoeI9/usE5hNM xRgB7qkgCSE6lBJnnwVCTMf6rIcWOx 3uqUU wPQZUERPCkD4iCta3eHEGIU5dBwFhLTk3yWiVrjBkrEyOcJmfdNg OVjlMokJjEJjojylJCTnOBnwVLd9AKQWxAWA7YJ5WC4 Fg1TGE42sIQ81CeTCw55MAmVEXychZILc/0VNUOxziRz/RMdUkR7pFxnmU3EqXqLhgZDi0RMgpbyBGY9k0kN58ppcDIlTGe3gSHby7B4CQEAgHlRl4mMpc8cK/yXyFmRDiSkQBysFwJiP1WS4DkJqVcD5MQ1oWA7ER qw4zkYTC8tOFDUlwIfmQCk8yOZWG1NxAOPlYkffKuO5d4CxB0A5gLBdtBgzKY50nJkeyY52YH9VX1hmwTJG4aRzKSjEiMpLNam3CsaZ57apyCZUjH7c 612vghTAtcYXqKzIla4k8SFMIBHha7HlonlPa8uMQArcmuh0bBeCI5S9QAYGVHKdACVvpAPDzKkkmCMKAOz8LJJxGVm9wyVxz8rBfAyT90xz9wglJz8AAqWm SR4JcMJwgclRE4SaZ9kq9IdkhIA/usOMxBUe7wsS6OUX1QiZpxysGoYJymNdBWScY8otegJA8bROUpkRMKKcR4CyH/OErT4VAOcCSDKaS4iI/VNcc84S3geUhm3blwEEY91th2BMytOjWBxK2WvOBz7KJJsZMSRB/smF08HKaQ4zlNJIXPJPtDJJPJSc6fkKMFLdHmFkkvYC3kn2S yROFgHC0qL7CxCd3Cy4zzIKwSYwsExknKWOmCFHslJIgJoMu5wsEuJ9kU3wxscXwBhMcYMCCFhx nKwDtCpQl2TkUZWSRHKYSAcBIkgSparKAQHnmEp2tTC6HD2KwXZIQmu0Mc4wARlNJ98LBfDflNcSeD91ca6Ac4gCVkGDMyoiADz ycId5TcXLKYGXmZymYPwsObCU Fm4 wHAfoksFxaElO2PYzxwN0gqZjtoAJWs10HKlDpHwvapPlEmwHSc4Um CFrtqQAOU9vkyU9v7EbDX/r904vMjla7Tn6gnjkESRwp47GTNk5JWHVQzJOFrurOpy48R4XOa51K3T2vIcAfYlFehHSm9pgkEx9ypGXLXGASUILzuKypWLfVbuHj3XTaH1WyrTZudlw8lRToDvw7GYWAc88LzrbUadw0EOBPsCt2k4PEj qNroCUnysz8lN8wswntfAGOCnALGAOUsnyk6jygHEhYgHwmOcGnJSFQGBysm/Qx5M P6ppBJGEi6PCYKh3D2U2I3bdnv y2QI4WrRcCc4WwICTpjHzGeVhzh/5TQZKaXE4hc8qQEkz/AOFgn5TA6MmQE6QRKxdegHtj3CREY5UYMkrAed0f1KSGsD58eUxz4MFNc7acFMc4EnyVpS9BZITtEhLfubn ihAPgrG eAZUtJdBY SVgmOE1ryRPhIkFNV0AtxB90jVJH9k1z48ZTQSMpK12IU7iFl0Dz 6w5wn5TSdy1UU8phY4wBgZTQ5YJJPCx/qpqgHHJS3GMLA/ZNJIRj0Ic4yMLEkD5TSQMnlYc4HkqbXDGO3AfZJMB3ARG35SWm2L6A8cOxHHypWnaIUVNpcJU7aZJGF7FIBwGVI3OFgNLRgSpBSJ/8AKVAJrhP id6m3zP2S9MkeFmnQlxBEpbEuAIKzHVGFrSSD4XD9X6FVvGkNBj4RFbS2gYTLm0ZWYQRM4V8CKta909dafWfUpteWjyPdedp/VV5YVSHBwHAn3Vk9Y6LpaizbtDQfZcx/wDSejud/KME88wECycn0f1rd3NzTa8EN4mOUZ9Hun3NBpcCSQuY0rtrSsagcGhuZwF29hp4tabW4gBJJBySNJiBkp3hThjSfcp0NaspNDI2sgTEn5TNhGfdTZMn9lkGYlc0hmq mSZKyaREY/otqGjMGUvHErJv9gazabichP8ARUpcsbisXq1gBtNhB8wpdxJxwm7sRwsbgEvy2BICeeEt6ic/anep8qG4vsB/qSBIWXVIwD igc44E5SmOShpLhgSud58rG/ySo9w90wuBwkrvkCZ1WMphqScBNNTA8Js8LWUpVygH854THcpTMpoM Vkpe0IeXfCwMglYPHH6pT/ALCtZAUzklIu90wmOcBJzhKbiA4nOU0uLc EzcsOMBRbXDAl3TGVG931eeEwOxEps5lVvnxyMeSSeeEtzlG53Cw2o4nnCiUJegJC47lG55B4wsucPsoy8ScopVlgSEnGElBvKSzwhGGgTEJ7WwcKBrpg5UrTBmV9GsICcH2UgctcuMc4UgcWx8pNX2ImbEElOBHsoQ8wIGVkPM ySRRsggBIKEEgEysipnKdBRLKQcTlRh4BnhYLzOCgVE 48ykH4UQcYzCzuxM/opabCiRrgPdO9QKDf7Sm7zKz2AbQqyIHKwX8qBrg0pOqALNpgTuqERlL1YWuXifhNLzJys25AbHqfKXqQPELV9QEe6Xqg/ouZuSYGyakn4WfUjHC1g/zKa58nlK2Bs7vlYNSPK1TUhL1dwQ5RSygNr1AfKwKgJWtvIWC/wArNtDNovhY9UAcqD1cJhqz9lm8iNo1PcrArD3Wt6gOPKwXgBLCGbDqwBk/0WfXEStPfu5Wd0GAnb6A2vWjzKYa491BvycphcCfdTuETmvJ4x5SNcDxKg3fKbuVptjNg1QUzfk5UReSsF8/EIV9gSF Ut8HKhDgPKa98cKrihE/qjKx6xHC1dx4WHP n4ScgNp1XB8lNNQASVrl0tmVg1MD2TjlXQGyKzSktXd7pLVbegJ2H2EBSsg//KwGYjlS02huSIle3QCa0HAGE nLfEj5T2MxgY9wnhp VSiK/Qh9QykGieU9rRyUi3blVsBsaB qdt5MJ20Dym 0BG2gsbwOJCwXeye45CbEzhQ4hbMAE/KdyFiYTWnaD/RTTC8GQSAsbyef6pTHhYJSHfsyTJ9knOBTTx7Jrjj3UtWJMe53GVG98TBTS/H3TZ Vg9MB  GpFxHCjBWC5YOKQyTefdKR8kqLcJWQ5YW0xkgcIysbuVHvgLIIPKvDEODjkrIf75UW DBysepmBwspQoCaQU0nM5/VMLljfmJlZbRkuD8FYIUe4TErBfnCW0RISAsbvsozVxwmOqRCai2gJt3Psml4BEKI1I yxuxhL8bvkZM5wmZ/RM9TKY54nlNq1mUwAHSr2V2BL6p85WHVQcSPsoC4xIOAsCq2CScppCJd/BjBWHPg 8rXdcMaI3StetfsowSceylwUngZu oQVh9SRPPwvO/xu3fO04HMkLFTWbdgjflV KVAeiHiOISLyeStKhdsuGbmuI VDqGsUrIGXRHJPCzUZrFCPSc9JeDT6kolhJcCeJlJbKNLMRnYUxLvIU7WAiOSsU6ZmTxytho4PhfVw8eT5IbMtpycqRrYwstaT8qRjASF3w8ZejNsj2RzhZDAfMKc0yDjKbBBy3Hst/46YtyISwg/CRZtC2AA7kQoyweDKT8Zeg3WQc8cLEqVzCxRlpkZC4NTx2uC06I4nymnJTiRuiRJUVaq2kJLgFwyg10UqscTATSfdRfiabh cSmPu6YIBcMrFxAmmfKaVqVtRoUWlxqfC1jr9rvDd4k/KhqgPSLsphMYUFG9p1m7g7Hj5Wpd6tStXne/6VPIG XLG AvGqdSW SHDIUFTqegymCT/Vc8o9WNM981B5CRdiQEOtR7nWljdGk qGwYyRK9Ch11Rr0PUa8OHiCsHCfRXJ2m7ExhYFUZQf6i70WuiOIrVg3nzCxpfd611Sh6tCuHAjwVltfYgwgyZmEhVhskIX6V3B/G3RphzjEcldnV1Q1NPL28BspbLYz1auoUqZAc8BNbqVvUwyo1zvgquPdLu9W6ae8NkObyB7Lyu3HeO46jq1N25kRjlaLTwBaB2o0WVYL5Psm1dXoDAdCFLeprkPBc6Qoq3UlbJJ5McrCajF0wCdcdQUbcA7wR9149XuDYNqhvrM3HG0uyhV1Trty3T3vY/bAwZ4Va9T661ZnUxpm5MB B4crhHTllgXvPWdv6RdvC2dP6kZeuDAQfsq4aRrta50Zm6s55IEu9/dd5231R9e7LH1JEDBPAVS0lVpCCtrmsjT7c1HYgTJQl6h76WOl3ApuqfUTxIyu367abjR3AEflkZ5VG 6pq2 v1KvqHLvyjEBEdJXTQLJczRu57dWtGVKT5B8B2Qt9vV3qU3Dcd3/bKr52Z1P8AF6NSdLS4N4P5/wDeESaVctrTiT4Kmem0/qwOvq9XvpuzLfglch1z3AudN099ameATM/2TK9xvr/V48eFyncln4jQa5GMcNVQ0s5YHI6N3 u7vVjQdUftJIBBgSidcdbXBtadY7muiRJVQNKrC16iwYG/EchWMoXzrzRaJxBYOPsut/XAw39u o6uqWxLnF5ODOEu49V9DTqldpd9MYB48f3XKdn67gx7N35Xe/P 5Xa9dURW0uscOG0rnllUxHA9PaxWr0XtNTdHk8pLw lqhpXtWm6XMiMFJPS8aMogWzo3tFp/MCfYlbIvabRucQAeIVPdC/iJfqXUFOxbVLiHbXScEIy6n1jWZoTqrTJ2SD7L7zQnDUuujmlfQWxrVruP8xuPC2RqdKJkQVSOn311N3VDbLftaXlpAMo ab1Jc19Lp1HViSWzg/C69PVWtezNGLb7YXamsU6bS8vBheHedc2VvVO sxhGMuhcFT1qrU0 qXvcHAGASqu92OudSs oX0qNw5rA TBic 6z19VaUdzHGO54Zd6j1xZV6ZIqgkexlS2fVdC5qtYHGScYVYe23UVxf6S19R7iXNGSZC7zpC/qnXfqqlzZADZwFnCbmk/YcOg7aldijZmqD4lcgOt2C6dS3iRjle5q5NbRTHtCCDqjma88OMQ/I VGq64NE0wpV sWtqgSN3vK5frDuMNLsqlZxIa0T8FePclxuWvEhvwuT7oNdU0Gr5dGB8Lg1U2sI0M6J35o6vqP4Zm8PB98Lp7/ALkVW7J oO4B8KqXb s6l1K4kyCfp Mo16w7dRpuEkiMLzWm RnUdWdyK9jpb6rWl20EgAoN6X351S712nQc0tpOfA uP3XV9Rn1tBqAiTskbvCrrTcbbqdgaC0h4iD8rFpgfQToPWamp6ax7nFxLZ V4vcLUbiyIdTdtz7rX7RXIraVbuJMFufH6J/dFpdbkng8LMZ4Ntq9zXshULoxyFIdRqXFk8bjuAwV5GjHfp7mzwMiVNRqg0qgBxHPsspQi8lAA7pazeW2tH/m3gSRBJCKPbXVql107RJLnktzJQo7x0Gsv9xwN3nkld52YuGv0BjJ4Ec5WMk/Yzhu89SrSvy9ri1okETx5W52hvX1rEtaSTxJ8rPe g6XOLCGgc CV4/Z26YHPZEPnH2 ElpRd0MN hXDqOqsz9UjAKONpWbU0n3Jb4VfLG4FHUmvBz8o89PVDW0lsuAO2cHCycVF4QFYv4h7cVKdZ8RGARz y4TsneVGaqGNIhxEyeEVf4ibUfhakfWI9uEEO1V 2y18bXFw4P8AqtVXsC0pqEhklPuSYaQIHwtKjX9ShSI8tHlTVnn0Rn90akW8gafULXV9Ke5sQBKqr1Kz8J1U87i0tf4PH6q1d 7dYPBks2mW 6qr3HJt pXua0sBdmVkn9lGxhu6QuRX0GnGRCIHbysaV4Gl2HGShR27uhX0GmJiGwCiD0Vcuo6sxpIBJkZXRqRX BBr6gb62lOA/wC3yqQ977QUdXJn5 I FeG4d6umOyD9OJ8KnXf6xdTujUFMgBx3H2KzjBp7rsXBs9h7z0qcbiSBAaROCeUaK7ibtpAIZHj3Vd yOo7Lx1MRuBkg QrBVHEem4GJC22OsDofcODHhxmOYXk9WsZcaNVnJLTtHuvRujFNp3AwtTVmtuNLeA76ts4WKjJPkkqPrLDYa7UBO0scQSEfukrg3ug03EHjECECu4FtUsuorgPAIc8wRn5Rj7dXhuenabQZO2CI4TnBzZXAVO2F2aN6 kHbdxnHlFPqCkK2mnc2WlvB8oH9D3DaOuMaQAZweZ Edb3dcaT9Rkbf2XJJNScbABuiu9HWalIEtBMAg454STbx7LfqlxMt3POR4 ElpCMdNU5f9Ar50fVLOsqD9p3b4PuFcarUFbpjbEO9LxxMcZVM9Brih1lSwQDVyPlXL093qdJh8n/p cnhfcfFRtTceTmk8qyqd3XNp1yCGDeKkD7SrddNVvW0G3IwC0QP0VRupaTbTrgvJH/VBb85jKtt0Q8P6Zo SW7iVv8AGve5xT44MtWN5o9mzc38NVaGwY5KqX3yY l1M7IkGHEe8q2dpIp1OJg5VWO/tM09fc9rYEyT5M Fp8lp/wBJWVpqkdt2YuC/QqTHEk/PgIn9MltHqBn1Agu5Qi7KXD32DT9O3b qKejuNLX6JaQQXiZPC28bSX8eO55MZS xYKo1tbRnkTwgPqILOo6kt2kvx7co6Wv8zRoJOW/2QP6lBo9SOEZnG7wo8iEIpSaLg2ehfucGsJ5nkLne4LQ/p6oYLnbZgeV0eoPDaFM 0SvG6opitoNU7p mIXDOO5YN/wDZWHQKho9XYwzcRg/KOFyQ zpPDsFsoI29B1DqxrQSP5kEFG8US/SqZDf8slci0Lu0NStmprIFTRKkZdtOY FXHU2in1IJOQ8EH4lWUuKPqaW mcYMFV06qt3DXXO2xJjHhc89BxHdlvOx1zUdpFAuxLeCZwun7kU21tOqOGC0TMLhOw92TpNIOcDgf kQ vaba lPkCNp4XDKNFIGehvL7RwGIJmCtu0d cTC8/QCSKrJ84W3av216gJ IWRQE 9dACq5xAmcGP15Xrdiro19PqU CHYWv3uohtvUeTEZHmTHELyuxF65lapTz9TsBZSbXAz2e9lq9li5xeC0/wBfhcB2lrmlqbwHYGYhEzvDai50x7nHaAP3KD/ba6NHXthOCf3T7AsBSqRc03wXHGAjh0fV3aWxpiY8ICsqO9SkZgeyNvQNYP05sGfpU4Tux9Az782odp9RrQCeZIVY g67bXqZkYJfEBWx730C7SqhE8HA54VPtGqOt q2EBwcamEJrmgLa2tQP0 kQPAMhbBfNtDpwF5ejV2v0qiSSTtEk 69GlVbVoEE7SfJUzmuOBEVR4fbPbMmMBVr7uUCzWt5y7z8KylMB1N4iD7oA96bVtK6LsEk4cPZTFNO RnsdqrhtfToJMgQD4RG6eqmlqzC0kmfKD3aC5IpvpBxy6YHCKul130tTYZ4OAVrJKroCxFo/wBbTIYDt24nyqv/AMQtsd9d 07fcFWW6erF2ktJ8tiJlATv7Z7qFYvaNpa4nP8Av5WULSEwI9pdQ/B66GmIdgmP9 6sp6wdQp8fdVQ7f1xbdTsY7cWvdt28 VaS3fNlRcAcN4PkJ2/7Qs3qlJlS2xlxHHuoGt22bmkGTghbFJzTQBgtMc ybPrUqjAAXxG5S43TaAq/3cty3XC/bABInkcrte0V2aliaby1wjgHI YXh967M0r/AHkkjgR9lL2bu4NRhb9XE/C0km GH6CzoTxR15jmHbnwefhH xf J0po/wD18qutKv8Ag9Xp7pndIJ4R86Yq/iNNYd0y0SB4MLFvPGR4BL1ixlh1GHFu0h07/mUl6PcqzLNVZUhoZ4BMpLJ6qWNj/wDBqyrtqx46q3OYRFSQ12MSrg6Fcm46UpkwHemJjyVT25eW9UANeHNNXkccq3XR49fpqiGkH6JX3nxMnHfHhnFO7srV1yH0 sy6sIcHckYGVaTt9XcelbcOEvDBMeflVi7mMqU tS7ZubvByflWQ7W1CelqTw4uloA/ F1fGOcNecJIz1fyKNo66yqkCoDAdBjKrL/ENRdT1VrwDsB qDkEqyVg41KtRu4Y91Xn I1pZcsIH1F2eeF1/ILfovonSc/7iTsfVNSx khpnAPxyi1ZuH NU3AbRuGB5QS7G1HbSd0AO458coyW9VtPVqRLnEbhmFyePFS0otysUprcWO0l2/RfJGzHygl1pFPXgS4 /OUYenKpqaQ36ifpmAhH3CJbqzSGgknkrq1m2qYou CS8cHWtF0y0gLU1pgfo1UQT9JIj7LYc/1LCmCIwk maumVGkjjkrCMVZTlSK43VoG9TOcGnd6kifBlGzTLA1dLokDc3ZH9EOamkE9TSId9eG8 Va7tj2k1DrKyoUra3c9zh4ER/Ze/o Cp6L1Jukv9Hn6nlRhKmwL1NKLrN7QJ D5VfOvNMda6w4mmQC8kmML6Xa7/AAzXeiWL6lWgXw0n/uA/ZUx78dBVNE1KpupQC7dkH7LN/HaPkaT1NGSlXpmUPPg57Wzd7DXG60YyfYRPCMHVzBV0l4JEbeEEOyW6hV2ggBoiPmUctdAqaU4 zZhfnnk6f4tRwPoIvdFNAa0R7vxtZrjtaCcrdpOi7eWyQvOtB6er1gTIJPlegCKd00RIXAzQGveWmXWFTzA3LiOylwKOsPaScuAyiT3XoCrpVVxb/lOUIu1lyLfqcU3DDieP9VDxyML/AHSAqaPVeRNNrchADo24bQ6nYdwDg4 FYvr6mLrRC0AGW POMKs m1vw3UoIiC/JH3yknYFim1A63pvmQQCEYe2d16tmwE4AkhBWyrNqWFJ4G5oEZRT7aXJ9NpHHssnKnXYzZ7uUBV02qdm7B n3HlUlvqotOpy4GWipiCrx9zKbrnSaojDmlUe6ooOtupnOiQKkjEeVMbcqSGWb6TuTX0WhwRtHC9yiQWEbZXI9t7l1fQqUknGZXVUiA52S2B7raWVlAPpTmXuAPhBjvdbfy2PDfcE/CMIeGvMEEHwhf3mtnVtPc9oyI/RZKukFnA9pLxrdQdSdPuBxmUZGtFK/pvBwTJygP24q nrTJGQcfujbUqvD6bmD6RHK1eY2ssA dF3RuNMa0cESh13vsPxGmV5GA0yMZXX9ubgmwDXEyB5Mrw 8NuaulVo5IgE/1WMYyTtsRTPS3/gOphgy2rGfurU6JWddaTRdUILiwceFVPUz E1/6htaH/UI VZjoi8Nz0/Qky4MH6pyUHmToDo6L/5RZEgeUy3eWPJmP7ptAjcWmPumNqE3BYBEKEk3hggRd7Lfcw1AIJMAn7Lh 1N6611Rw2kk8wfCJveCx9XTHS6MzPug70PUNvrtOfyboJ F0pfUA63jy vScHfSeSeUdugb51bSqYxkePKBFzH4em9sQIiUXO1t6Xaaym5wjwSsK7iwNHuxTNJ1OrDSeIJykvR7nW4rWLi0Z4kxlJRKm7cmOynuqNFLqRzQ0NDagMg8 f7q2fbyqKnTlNrHiA0CJnwqmdUUfS6hq/8A43 p9iFaHtPcM/4YoGYdsied2IlfX/GTWnqSUlZx6idfXkC3d9jB1OQJH8wtcOD90de0lx6/T9INIJa3aROceUDu9LCzqE1PJfmUXOy1089Ps3DdtbzP6L0/Db/kzpmWtlBHsm/8w8hwnygT/EVSbUa14BOYMeSjfZ3LfxbgBGJhBn IWlUrW27Ecjwt/NlH8LXZnop3dnHdkKpFy9jZn3JwjZVuWNvaO4jcTwfKAfZmsRqtRpLhERCN9xUBuqJjIjK5fFT/AApLoclUixfSVY1NHZH0wwYCGHcz XqDHzmUQegbhtfR6ckk7Moe91Ghty124AzHC69VP8e6hwhnBFSr pp7A0wIxKzbu3WL5Mx7rV097X6S1wdJDeCFi1uv TqNGTBwFyQmo5sqUZNHFsbQtupmVKroirOPuvoj/D53T6Z0Hpy3oXLmWj9oDnkSD q XXWXURs9bADYgnIPOfdFHozrS5qaMwiq4EgY3T4X1s9XxvN8NeNqvHOD53yPHktZakej6a9W/wAQvSFhaVWNrC8qQYYBhfOb KjuRpms3dT8NQaxm4gg8rzrjqa6q1HNLi8eZMlBDu7qb69YvJMt5zhcHjvxvioS/jNtyxk0elPX1FPU5Ow7L6qauoENcNsySrC37y7SiZGWxIVTuxl//wA QS0F7hH6cK1Tqgq6M5pBEthfB bqPV1ZTPptKOyCQFbio6nr9UNwA4hbtSo5l03JBK8/ViaHUDzyCeFt3J21qZGZXlOObs2PD7itc/S6m12C32lAboWs2h1ZTAdkOx8/f4Vget4qaK8RLgPbwq5aRU/BdYMLcNFQcfdKkBY3qFhq6GSGAks4/RVev3fhOp/yx/M448qzt4Tc6A0iQC2cYIwqw9SUnUddc4/Sd5IHxKypdIaDzpFz6uj0HAH8oKJXbO8Lq4ZIjyEKOj634jQaJnhoB 6JHbyr6V9AcI5LU7lV1QJBG63otq6U8mfymIVH 5Nq216ieQeXzBV6eo2GtpLo r6eJVKO8Vpt1t7gI2uhXFtrIBO7QXwraOxrXGIjPuu 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 SrG9oqxqdOUthaRtwYVdOvKRo628lud3B 5R77JVg/p4AOgiB9sL3vjZvT13KXFHNKO5UDzvYzbqgLzsql3MeES xd0DoDKbXOEN88ErgO/lOLqnUgB5MFx f/S6vsPcbdJBJBHER5XTDVf8AKddg40vYW7eWXp4yMwhV3/3nTgWmGgQ4xxnCKFKpsvGukAFDXvq/doziRIA5IzyvR16cGpMiP ARdoLks11wB l DIR0vKxBokTn5VfO2906nrzRT43QZ4R8vXw2k6QQIC4fFk1piklYfuga23SaX1CdvjyuR7qxDSW5mZ9l7HbiuH6XQLnw4NA 2Mrx 6pbs3xuj3W85/UcYJZPF0iqH6Rs5dBKjsrgClV28weVqdP3Bq6a4Hzx8JWcNq1AR9RXHLUajSL2AK7tE0NWL52SZAXY9tNWP CNDn7iQQAfC4nvcHM1UucCGyIPhbvay9fU08tkQ3knlRHynG08A4JhMoX5ddOk7gf6IU94K9Nji04cROV3bbmLkCdv2Q87uDfQJgGBl3lZavltqkSoUR9j74DVw0OlxIhv2PKuNp9Z1TSm7nZjlUc7P3Ro65Sbt3EugT4V2dFqNq6a0NONuJXkyd5NkCfqqW9QbzGTEqa4qYpkgR7qHroGlrQJgfZYrO3W9L7cysUyiHqZoraRWjO5hgqtF2W0eqgQNxNQHHgyrNamN kvAgnbAnIVZ pKYtupW7IaQ8EfupfoZYmwrtuOnGN4imPp/RVu67pubrtVxaGgVD VWH6XeKvT7XuIktxKBPc62/D6o8jMuklUsAEHt/cmroNNsgCP1RG6GrbdWYZGEJ 2Vb1NMa2ADHKJPSlYU9UY1v0kuRa4AOt /wBXSXQ2TtxCpz3xo7b95pgkAmXAfKuDSPq6XmYIwqp99rdwuKh9MhsbiZ8/7lJP9DR5XZS8eKlRrnS0xH39kaqhcHtc0QCgB2ivhRvmskAkyAj9UfIYS6ZHEpNpDFV3AtBdnlaXUlM19LdLZwVvV A8ZwtXUwa2n1BGI4U94JZV3Wf V194b9MPwjT0vWdV0Wk2QfpCD/XVA22uFzgJ3In9A3ZqaO1pJ 8K7odhS7eVxSvJ4f8APhFXVw6vpLyYP04CC3Rld9DUoaYkjnkiUban8/SPpEnbgKXKhFLu89k5ur1Kh2gc7RiP0XpdlNQAq k9 AOI/wBFtd8rT0rskMAdkcfdct2lvvT1hvAcMREyi8UgZYOq4suRDsH3SvzNPdzPlQ3hZ9LpkQM FPcgVbZu3iFm9ydtf9GebrDfX0yo0SYEEqs3VdE2 uVTt2w9WjrPmwcHY ngBVq7h23pa3UcTtO6cHlVCVsEEvoS5FxojActY3j3C7roK9NHXGSdrZIB8FDPtdcmtYbAPpHuZld909XbR16luwC4HHAVbs0MPmoO9bScHJGSElizq ppQa76xGCAElZOCj/cRrxqwqSYJwCJRj7I3BdpUMjaOTPx/wCEIu4ry6/eSNv1kgfqiZ2OrtZYEB2x8AQ3z916sGoazRB5vfXL8tJI oOXo9hrovtQwtDi2RuHI 61O DPXokkiG5ha/Yqu6m4sDQ4AZIweVrGUn5Nt4JfAczUIvGBxgHyVwne1zq gghxcASSW/byuyrvPrsJg5XId16rX9PVP8mOR8 F2a9yg1uM4or/ANvqpZ1JQ2umHx9RwrC3zibeiTlsDhVt6RcbfqOmJLXF8YxCsPUrufpzKk8CYK87RlSyahm7YXG7Tg0kyAIlRd1GuNgSBuf/AKhaHaa7FSzb9RMmYIwvS7mk/wCF1XkHA/2F1ykpRBHEdMVgbN8ugiYIKktqxfXdIz5IXmdK1WuZVBkD2C3LepN69nLJxHK4pScY8jA13wpk3G5rzHseAPC1e0t06pbVGE7tphej30o7G7mzkRk FzfaK4LalRoME FzKb4AJb3ll03BIBXGd0GbtPc8QQT48FdVe1Hi7awnbJyVzXcZjamknMuA5CzboDhO1936fUlFogDdyVd3pS59XS2HyW8eyoh0RUNr1FSfgw8ecK73QdUv0pj93Iwsm/Yziu4NM09S3HILlq7h EpugnAXp9yobch5cD5heLaVd nTJxwsnOKdWOjZuyKumuxtAECFXLr6j6Wvl3gOx8qxlA/iLF7TAdGAVXjuYzbrBcZALlSzkLoL3QVV1105TLn7htiR55yhR3boll8S3jnKI/a q5 gtBMtiNoK4Xu/b/zicNIkq7GSdqbgVLWoJ/LARK0OoP8AE6YnG6TCEPai4muaZ lvmPP3RTtKgtdRpu/KNwkqbAsNpVQv0oNd7Kuffqz2MrvI2gifgyj309XdU0uCZLggz3xtTUt6xA4bGT ySoAG9srn0teYMYPBCscwmpQovAjHsqxdG3DbLqKmXjaA6He/KsvaVvV0 k5jpECHBPkZtvcKdPcct8wo7hzqto4sbwCpA0Poz58qFlWaFRu0jH5gk2kBXTuiws1d7tsZmfldX2xuzWsdpkiP2Xj93LQNug5oBqESTCf2ruSWmmRxk7RwqXGBBY0N/patTLTEnmeEdNNuBcaW3kNDeFX61aHX1MAEiRkmEeOmKoq6WA7w3hZ/ZsCvvfGyFdtR8AEE5HI 6D/bm8Np1AzAMuj4CPPfGxDKdRzWgbjh39vsq6dO1n0 oWhoAcXwScAZTirWeQLQu3Ps6TnEF 0fAWy15fa7Q2SVoWVZlxo1Et/7QQfiFt2teLZ3BMYwq/TAzQY02tQAEOA85Ve 69rs1Fz4G0 fPuj/AGT5LxJB8AIN947YNeKvDstLSOVOL ozX7S1HuPpseQ1oLiESKTzS1ekWhoMoPdrtQNPUA0gNBO0keyLV1Uey5Y4cGOFWXyH A 9NVxcadg7m7R/okvP6Eud kU/tiElFPoaKi9yWepfuJIaI/eCu27IlrWkFsEf5yZ/2FxPcF4F1u2yACIHkrpezd2d7wAGgNH/APS9LTe6doyZ73eSmz8M6q4/SQRheD2Yudt09rXbRMAnyve7rn19OBDQ0sJOOXThcb2irejrZbUkteYa39UPdLUQiwNRw9Zsuk 68DuPtqdP1B7tIn5XrVqswR9P3Xj9dsNbQHw6DtJBXVrSlH6PkOEVt09/o9RgtdMPwRhWDoVTU0mk6OWjCrpbOLepA4S0B/KPenXBdpFOJ27RBOFnoSlFOSAKvay6c2i5hblp5ldT3Empo1RxDj9PAPK4XtTefW4/mdMcccLuOuau/SHkt2w0j9wlLUcltGCvpes9rqrXAH2hblKt6eovJnJXjdN1dt/VaeT49l6lWpGoZ4OPsufaxsHneqkKltuJgxgTz8FD3te8s1AtL9o90R 8dOdJJcc ChZ25f6Golu4ncVjwILmoOBrsIMwY3LxOumippBLWl2PZere1AzYfEjIWj1W31tIftII2zKhjA501cGj1FTJwA//AGFdvtrVDtIpBvhoEyqN6fFPX2yCRu4Cud2luqbtIZBhxbP08H5SGN7oMhhqDkf5o5XKafd77AAjEey7TuVTFS2A3YiQCuD0ncLZzXGR4KloD0beX0nwcEeSgd3Utwy c7dmRlG yEtc2ZJ8HyhD3dtvSq7iG7j/AJfiUgPd7QXgqaeacndzzheR3ftwZJcA4THzhP7PVSWVGAYxIW73UtQ 3NTkDB E8gcF2yrAajtLo8Itsqlt1TAHlBPoYClrdP6oId5RorS11KoJj3USipcgg59GVTV0tjZAdEfCHvea2L7aqTO0A5C7PtzcNqadTJMOiM V4Xdy09axqmc7eI5T6GVH02KGvsJJ/wCoIn7qyXTtb19FYWw4gQD7qtN5FDX8gj Zj4yrFdG1XXOiU8gECP8ARVS5A6CiHuoEYyOAm21Rx3MxEQlau3B37BRUmOZVeCInmPCoayCLvDTjeQ0CIEnlc32xvCy9qM3YfGJXd91rJlxZHG0 /shj0PU/C6uwNjdugbkMQbKRcbimQ7YAco19E1m1LADduEePCCbs m9vGMIsdu7gGi1pxA4nn2WVOWGwZzHem0dX06s1gkQTJ5Cqiw/htczja/n9Vczunairp9QBoMgzH2wqba2wWuuvkmA/z5TSptsRZDpSsbjQKVQkEFkTGV62nvLC4RPwuZ7e1W1OnaY2zHzPK6SzcPUcMtPGVSmuijFKmKV2 fpB9kN 7doatoduC3EnPKI4cWXUkgiYhch3WtBW0io5oAIHMIr0gAz0HW/D6zTDsEO8eUcbip6lJj4MjyfIVf8Ap6q221pgLjJfE/qjsK7zpzIhxDRlVw8gFztxcGpasO7a3iP0SXkdqrr1aPpAmQd0nhJRT5QyvXcln84ubDRnwt/s5cf83UY7ILRDfmcrQ7gMq p9QbBmMyFjtQ91PVgAKYdBhzv7LpTdkBB7o/8A2vbz4zxlD7tnUdS1um5zpDSZ yIfcNnqaU WgktGfIQv6Cc4dRNotkkk cITaaEywdWo2WuIJkCIWt1M/fpD2tz9BA MJVK7jRpSQ0wJPysawPV0p5iDt5 F2z1oTX7FRWa/Jpa0NxMbsnzyjjoVXdoFJ0yYjJlA/qSGa46XHdu9oRf6SuBU0SmBAIaAR7/K5VOlQdhK7YV9l8N5IBO0D 6JXVrvV0urAn6fCEvb28cNRAaNrpiSivrs1dJc2Idt8KdzYwP6IGs1h4B4M/IXo3ryL2eQV41k99HXKhAGXYXsXrz Ia7huMQo38oGcl3SpipojnkSAPKDPQlY0tfIH5XY OUcO4tsami1XCQNsoE9MObT6gYeWbsjyoYUGbUhtpMcPAEj3WtrbTU0VxaOW5WzqDZt2ADAaJhMvgHaE8A/URiVIwE1GOo6zzB3YI 6tz2Zuo06j9W76QMfZVG1Os6nrMgB31eytJ2RuCNMoGZBPPvKBnd9w6YdYF7weMIdaLBpvAyfZEvrZnq6a/ySMTwEMdKdtqPAYAQYJCBG/agsqn38IY936BdTc8D6sAyUS6Lv5ziZycBcJ3XoOfaE7SYEmMyf/CTkhnM9oagF2QXQWkH q63ue1r9MqBoIkecCVw3ap7m6uWgSBzHKJfX9l K0V8NJ2if0QuMCAR0yfT1oB2CHcHyjiINCkY9oCCGnWtajroexhI3TkI40Les7TqT3sduIB3QkgCl27qhlsJ5njype51IP02o5syW4JXn9uqL6bQarXAzP3 69/ruyqXWmVRSaXywwAnVLA ClHUlNtLX3OGYejl25uvU0RggOMRgob9T9A6rcavvoWp2k5HEIpdtelb3TtM2V2EVHcCDACWGI6C2Ox5AMZ8pCttuCZnxC9ah09Xp1SXZnnCk/wCFa7rgv2Hb4JVVXAwZdybc17JzzxBwPHygv07VNHWAd0fUOPurUdT9BVtSsi0fUSIiEOdM7D3FHVW3Bktad0twE7Eeg2oKtvTcBDoRG7dVnNAbIn2UFHt451qGhskYBAXU9KdKu0fJaS7guU7ijU7gUfW0us5zQTsIglU06wsn0tYeHMj6pDlezWtKOo276ZbO4Rn2Q61Hstb6hU3FrAQZBjyh54AHnaV9V2lhjmH0gPpx5Xa06Fand8QOV2fTfbijoVFlNuWQJHsvbZ0xQ3uc5oPgNKUW wBfXsqrboEtcQT4C87rrSKt1ozhTpl73CBhGhvTlsXSGAEeyVx0zb3DCHtDmkQR8K8hwUjseidQ/wAZGyg/D/bgI2aT07cP0v0QN08bhwjPS6I0yk/1GWrQ7HhejS0G0otJFFokRwk3XIA77eaPWsq72GmdnJPsUkTLOxpWgIY0MnyklFtcjRS7uLSJcAyBnn3wvP7Yvc3VgBDSTBMeF1fV/TF3dNc m0zzB91odv8Apm7s9S31qL6bBlWqRB23XzW1dHLm4huYOShB0jU9DqOm95cBviT4R31/p2te6Y6Gugtx/wCkPdI7d31LWGVXU/oBmYkK7GE/e2tat99uFFe1tulva7MiJ9l7FHp oLFgILKg5gLYq9KOrWtSm9shwOcrSU3J5EVO6mpxrdQ1CSWvIn3hFboja7SKYDTkZgcL0dY7IV7/AFH1QHMZMkASSV23T3bh m2Io7S2BtyP6rJMdI87oOsKWrluHQYgjlGC eG6a0kzIyJXKaF0O3T7plYAu Y8rs6trvtvTwGkRBSYJWBN1N46hqbQQASf/AXp3gr1KlOGnaF3v/Btu64NYgF58Kf/AIWpvILpAHslVifIJOsLa4utFqt2k03NIiEDtF6cv6Gusm3fAfJgK6Vfpa3rUSwjBwZXmU 3OnNrCp6bQfIHlJ2AI/8ACLitZsDmOBLRgLYf0xc19Oc1rD WGz7/ACja3p22bRawMAAxwpRolBoAAB 6dWBTvVO1Gq19VL20voDpk yOfarpm70ehRbVc6ABiMIn09AtA7d6TS77LbtrKlbN2sYGjiApoDzNf0839k5kRI4XHaf0TWoVqjoJa8/sib9Lseyxtaw4CYHDN6RLnfWzI8rzNe7cU9VaWlsgiMonCC3jlZgeyTBAc6d7M0dJvhXYzZtPAEBw V2N90LRuqG0sG4iPhdiAIJ4 yduJPCWEMGFr2asqVy2q6nTjyAMldRR6It6Nu2m1rSBj68rqPfCU4RSQjy9P0NmnmWQB8BblzaNuGbScfZT IWZMERlOkM8R3SVjUqb30ml4/zRlblpottZg myceVvJwOITwDNdun0S/dtAMeVMLZgyGgfonkAeyzuwRx qTdCIjbsOS0JNpU2kQ3j4TtxjKXGSpbfQGSADPCeIn2TDJz4S4GQmt3Y0OjOI/VIgTjlNMFYESqyJ8jxxxhZIDU3gYlIEHnlIY/aBHzykI/9rG7OUoJCaAc12eFl0EhNEtBwsmIiDKKAyIcJEnKSwxvpk PdJK0uSgeXOg2NwGepQa DIlbFpolnbvYWUWg/ISST7Ej1a1lR9Nv8sH9EmaVayD6QEeySS0RK5NynaUqYO1sKWnQZt/KEkkW7AdToMknaE8gAn6R ySSFwMyANogR9lIQCDhJJSxMxEPCw d/KSSkTHP hpIP7pN5CSSaDoyTgpRLZSSTYPgaBkrEkmEklIzLclPAkJJIExU E2oIJyUkkDYm5apC0RKSSaKQwE5TvA 6SSlkjoWHOJdCSSYmKU4NxKSSQ0YHKa8wkkgfQgZErPJSSTQIzJmJSHlJJAzCwcpJIZMR0flTyNjoHBSSTRSMBoLktx3R4SSSAeMhO3kOhJJKRRgfUcpJJKI5Q6P/2Q==
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: The data URI is of MIME type `image/jpeg`, which is *not* a bitmap.

Comment: I thought the jpeg data was base64 and could be turned into a bitmap, is that not correct? @SpencerBench

Comment: Sorry, you're correct, the `Bitmap` class does support decoding JPEG files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Scan(string file)
        {
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf(',') + 1));
            Image image;
            Bitmap bitmap;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
            {
                image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                bitmap = new Bitmap(image);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is incorrect.

The base-64 data starts after `base64,` in the data URI. Note the comma. Your regular expression includes the comma in the `data` capture group. You need to put it *outside* the capture group:

```
@"^data:((?<type>[\w\/]+))?;base64,(<data>.+)$"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately I failed to copy my code correctly.  I will update the regex, but am unfortunately having the same error.

Comment: @micahkimel Have you double-checked to make sure that `base64Data` contains all 19,632 characters of base-64 data, as expected?